# Laravel: Login screen if not logged in errornbh

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

First Laravel Project. I want to redirect not logged in users to the login screen.

I configured the auth like in the documentation and found this `routes` script somewhere:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
```

and pasted it on the beginning of the `routes/web.php`
But now it drops to the `myip/login` and got routing error.

How to fix it?

(i know that if I delete it it will be fixed, but I want this feature.)

**EDIT:**
Route list:

```
---------------------+----------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                          | Name                 | Action                                                                 | Middleware     |
.
.
.  
|        | GET|HEAD | login                        | login                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,auth,guest |
|        | POST     | login                        |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,auth,guest |
```

**EDIT2:** The error message

> The site is not properly diverted
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request in a
>   way that will never be fulfilled.
>
> This problem sometimes occurs because of a disabling or refusing to
>   accept cookies.

I got almost the same message in Chromium, too

**EDIT3:** `routes/web.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
//AUTH

Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@index');
.
.
.
My other routes what are working perfectly
}
```

Comment: Have you run this command `php artisan make:auth` ?

Comment: Yes I runned it

Comment: Please run the command `php artisan route:list` and check if there is an entry for `/login` ?

Comment: @linktoahref I updated the question with the output

Comment: Please Could you also post the error

Comment: @linktoahref Added to it

Comment: please add routes available in web.php.

Comment: @PankitGami added it

Comment: @Feralheart There is issue with your web.php. So add the code of web.php. Not the output of route:list.

Comment: Shouldn't `Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@index');` be outside of auth middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want guest to visit the index page. If you don't want guest to visit index page put it inside the `auth` group.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

   //AUTH
    .
    .
    .
    My other routes what are working perfectly
}
```

You need to put your index and login route outside the group.

**Edit ::**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::auth(); // If you have this line, place it above the `auth` middleware.

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

   //AUTH
    .
    .
    .
    My other routes what are working perfectly
}
```

In your login form change route like this :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
```

Comment: I don't want to show index page if not logged in, but `/login` still causes problem if it's outside of `auth` group

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I got the same 'Site is not properly diverted' message

Comment: In your route list, login route is pointing to `LoginController@showLoginForm` action. In your `web.php` it is pointing to `HomeController@index`. Isn't it strange?

Comment: Yes it's strange

Comment: The action is what you wrote, but the problem is still exist